# What are those types of pointers called and how do they work?

Tags: c++, pointers

I did an hour of googling trying to understand the usage  of pointers in this code to no avail.

```
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

class Node {
    public:
        int data;
    Node * next;
};

int main() {
    Node * head = NULL;
    Node * second = NULL;
    Node * third = NULL;

    head = new Node();
    second = new Node();
    third = new Node();

    head->data = 1;
    head->next = second;

    second-> data = 2;
    second-> next = third;

    third-> data = 3;
    third-> next = NULL;
}
```

I am confused about how these pointers are used.

```
Node * head = NULL;
    Node * second = NULL;
    Node * third = NULL;

    head = new Node();
    second = new Node();
    third = new Node();
```

Why does the pointer point to the constructor of the class?Shouldn't it point to a memory address?
What is this particular technique of using pointers called?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What makes you think that the pointers "point to the constructor of the class"? There does not appear to be any sophisticated pointer techniques at play here. You simply store three `Nodes` on the heap, and access them via pointers.

Comment: I assumed it since I read that constructors have the same name as the class and that a default constructor is called if there isn't one in the code

Comment: That is correct. The default constructor is called, which returns an instance of `Node`. What part of this suggests to you that you are "obtaining pointers to `Node::Node()`" (which, by the way, [is not possible in C++](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/245613/why-doesnt-c-allow-you-to-take-the-address-of-a-constructor))?

Comment: It sounds like you need to find a good C++ book. The behavior of the `new` keyword is fairly fundamental, and you shouldn't try to learn it just by googling around.

Comment: In the separated part of the code,three pointers to the class Node are declared and made NULL.
Then the pointers are made to point to the constructor of the class Node.
That is what I am understanding from reading this code.
Please correct me.Thank you.

Comment: nope, they are pointing, because of *new*, to the *result* of *calling* the constructor. Not to the constructor function at all!

Comment: I will try to learn from a C++ textbook then.Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh... These would be called "Node pointers", or "pointers to nodes." Their purpose is to point to `Node`s. ;)

Snark aside, your understanding of pointers themselves seems okay: Pointers store the memory address of some piece of data.

In `head = new Node()`, you've misunderstood how the new keyword and constructor interact: `new` allocates memory for a new object, calls the class constructor, and returns the address of the newly created instance. In this case, then, `head = new Node()` creates a brand new `Node` object in the memory, and returns the address - which is then saved into head`.

It seems you might benefit from a good reference on C++, as a few comments have mentioned before. I can recommend [Learn C++](https://www.learncpp.com/) if you aren't the type for books. You might find useful the [introduction to pointers](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/67-introduction-to-pointers/) and the introduction to ["dynamic memory allocation"](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/69-dynamic-memory-allocation-with-new-and-delete/), which is all about `new` and it's counterpart `delete`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation and the tips.
I guess I know what I need to do now,make my learning a bit more structured instead of reading whatever that comes up on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org lol

Comment: You're welcome @FlyHigh. Yeah, learning to code C++ can be a frustrating experience at times: Reading through rigorous tutorials and books takes forever, but quick Googling often results in answers which are *almost, but not quite* relevant to what you're doing. You're making good progress. Have fun out there!

Answer (score -1):

The pointer points to the constructor class because the constructor class returns a pointer to a new object.
Essentially, `new Node();` allocates a space in memory for a new node returns the memory address at the beginning. Thus, the line `head = new Node();` initializes head. Without this, `head->data = 1;` would generate a segmentation fault since head does not reference any space in memory.
Feel free to respond with any further questions